# Dagster getting partition using different timezone

Tags: dagster

I would like some help in scheduling a dagster job that should get s3 folders on a different timezone. For example it brings all data s3:///2023/09/01/00 to 23 (i.e all hours). But what I want is it to bring  s3:///2023/08/31/22 and s3:///2023/08/31/23 + all folders from s3:///2023/09/01/01 to 21. This is because I want the data to be pulled in Europe Timezone as opposed to UTC (which is what the data is loaded in)

We tried using the timezone feature in the

```
partitions_def: DailyPartitionsDefinition = (
    DailyPartitionsDefinition(
        start_date=backfill_start_date,
        end_offset=0,
        timezone="Europe/Amsterdam"
    )
)
```

This did not seem to help.

Comment: Those aren't dates or hours, they're flat file names. You'll have to parse the filenames first if you want to treat them as dates or times. In S3 and other cloud providers, containers/buckets contain a flat list of files. Folders are *emulated* through special characters like /. Searching "inside" a "directory" is essentially a prefix search

Comment: BTW you'd have the same problem even with a local folder structure. The folder names are just strings, not date or time parts

Comment: `I want the data to be pulled in Europe Timezone` why? This matters a *lot* and could cost a lot - S3 partitions requests based on prefixes. Instead of scanning the prefix `2023/09/01` you'll have to scan 24 different prefixes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the reason I want data to be pulled in Europe Timeezone is because the data is stored in UTC. I see that a few records that have timestamp of 11PM is missed out

Comment: You're repeating the question without actually explaining *why*. You don't need to scan the files to generate reports in another timezone. Once you import and process the data, you can convert datetime columns to different timezones as needed, even in your report engine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, source data is stored in UTC. As it stands, the job extracts one day's data in UTC, because of this, some transactions get missed out (these are transactions that happened around UTC midnight). So I want the partitions to be calculated and picked on another timezone and not UTC.

Comment: I suspect you haven't read any of the comments and assume I didn't understand. Repeating the same wrong question 2 times won't make it less wrong. I've worked with S3 and Dagster before. I repeat *for the last time* that those are just filenames with no meaning as far as Dagster is concerned. Where's your parsing code? The asset code? Have you tried *anything* yet? What you posted isn't relevant. `DailyPartitionsDefinition` isn't applied to datasets automagically, you have to specify it in the assets